# Spring boot service to return large datasets from oracle database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring boot project with JPA hibernate.

My requirement is to return data from database based on the sql where user can choose to fetch all the records from last 30days.
The data is going to huge in this case.

I tried using @Query in my jpaRepository, but the results are taking forever to load on the browser.

Any ideas on how can we make if fast?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the whole data in one single go, you can go for Pagination.
The backend will take the limit and the offset and make subsequent requests to load more data as is needed.

You'll need to pass an object of `Pageable` while Querying the database.

You can refer to the following link for more information on how to achieve it:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to implement Paging. is there any other option to send the entire data at one shot?

Comment: If you HAVE to load the complete dataset, I dont think there's any other way. You can however, also do async calls with pagination to the database and store their data in a `Future`, aggregate the data and return. I am not sure whether the performance will improve or not. Do let me know how it works out. https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture